# Windows realtime microphone noise gate frequency filtering

Tags: windows, audio, audio-recording, microphone

I'm trying to enhance my microphone sound, the sound will be used for multiple application and recorded, I can modify the recording easily, but I don't find anything for the real time.

I'm looking for a software, or a set of software that can enable the following :

Real time sound from microphone modification, with the smallest delay as possible ;

Filter frequency  for active noise reduction ;

Add an additional gain ;

Provide a threshold for the microphone activation.

I found the software NoiseGator for the last two point, but I can't find anything on the frequency filtering, and I really need to reduce the static noise of a crappy microphone.

So, here I am asking for your help, Do you know any software that can help me achieve that, or even further microphone enhancement ?

Thanks

Comment: https://forum.audacityteam.org/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=82147 may be helpful.